# I am struggling a little on getting this code to work in python

Tags: python

Now honestly, I think this could be entirely wrong as I don't really know what I am doing and just kinda through some stuff together, so help would be appreciated.

This is the code I got, including starting code that cannot be changed.

```
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY CODE IN THE MAIN FUNCTION
def main():
    input_file = open('strings.txt', 'r')  # Open a file for reading
    for line in input_file:  # Use a for loop to read each line in the file
        manipulate_text(line)
        print()


def manipulate_text(line):
    # Delete the following line, then implement the function as indicated
    line = line.upper()
    line = line.strip()
    letters = []

    for char in line:
        if char.isalpha():
            if char not in letters.count(line):
                letters[char] = 1
            else:
                letters[char] += 1

    for everyLetter in letters:
        print("{0} {1}".format(everyLetter, letters[everyLetter]))
```

The .txt file it uses just contain:
Csc.565
Magee, Mississippi
A stitch in time saves nine.

And these are the instructions I have been given, also in this .count is what needs to be used, as shown in my code.

The `manipulate_text()` function accepts one string as input. The function should do the following with the string parameter:

⦁   Convert all the letters of the string to uppercase, strip the leading and trailing whitespace, and output the string.

⦁   Count and display the frequency of each letter in the string. Ignore all non-alpha characters.

For example, if this is the contents of strings.txt:

Csc.565
Magee, Mississippi
A stitch in time saves nine.

This would be the output of your program:

```
CSC.565
C 2
S 1

MAGEE, MISSISSIPPI
M 2
A 1
G 1
E 2
I 4
S 4
P 2

A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE.
A 2
S 3
T 3
I 4
C 1
H 1
N 3
M 1
E 3
V 1
```

Comment: In `main()`, use `with open() as` instead of `= open()`. It ensures your file object is handled properly, even in case of an error.

Comment: For this I cannot change any part of main()

Comment: It shouldn't affect anything at all if your code runs properly, and it's good practice, but oh well then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code you wanted:

```
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY CODE IN THE MAIN FUNCTION
def main():
    input_file = open('strings.txt', 'r')  # Open a file for reading
    for line in input_file:  # Use a for loop to read each line in the file
        manipulate_text(line)
        print()

def manipulate_text(line):
    line = line.upper()
    line = line.strip()
    letters = {} # Dict[Char: No. of occurrences]
    print(line)
    for char in line:
        if char.isalpha():
            if char not in list(letters.keys()):  # If char not in our dict
                letters[char] = 1   # One occurrence
            else:
                letters[char] += 1  # Add one occurrence
    for i in letters:
        print("{0} {1}".format(i, letters[i]))
        
main() # Call main
```

**Output:**

```
CSC.565
C 2
S 1

MAGEE, MISSISSIPPI
M 2
A 1
G 1
E 2
I 4
S 4
P 2

A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE.
A 2
S 3
T 3
I 4
C 1
H 1
N 3
M 1
E 3
V 1
```

In response to your comment:

```
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY CODE IN THE MAIN FUNCTION
def main():
    input_file = open('strings.txt', 'r')  # Open a file for reading
    for line in input_file:  # Use a for loop to read each line in the file
        manipulate_text(line)
        print()

def manipulate_text(line):
    line = line.upper()
    line = line.strip()
    letters = {} # Dict[Char: No. of occurrences]
    print(line)
    for char in line:
        if char.isalpha():
            if list(letters.keys()).count(char) == 0:  # If char not in our dict
                letters[char] = 1   # One occurrence
            else:
                letters[char] += 1  # Add one occurrence
    for i in letters:
        print("{0} {1}".format(i, letters[i]))
        
main() # Call main
```

In reponse to your **second** comment:
Use these instead of `manipulate_text()`:

1. If you don't care about ordering:

```
def manipulate_text(line):
    line = [i for i in line.upper() if i.isalpha()]  # List comprehension!
    for i in set(line):     # set() changes it to all unique keys, loses order
        print(i, line.count(i))  # .count()
```

2. If you care about ordering:

```
def manipulate_text(line):
    line = [i for i in line.upper() if i.isalpha()]  # List comprehension!
    uniques = []
    for i in line:
        if i not in uniques:
            print(i, line.count(i))  # .count()
            uniques += [i]
```

Comment: Yes, originally I was going to use keys as I saw when I first did research, but in this they specifically want us to use .count instead of .keys, I am so sorry about that

Comment: Is there anyway to completely exclude using .keys and only use .count, the entire code under the second section under def manipulate_text(line): can be changed if that is a issue as this code was just thrown together by me, I just sorta hit a wall, I am sorry that I am being so picky about it, the person I have to show this to is just very peculiar about how they want things done

Comment: @Forgetten Added. I recommend the `set()` method, it's much faster, but of course it won't work if you need the ordering preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was honestly really struggling on this so I really appreciate you getting me through this!